# jQuery-ui draggable element into CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor, jquery-ui-draggable

I was testing a different feature, and I somehow, accidentally dropped an image that I had rendered "draggable" with jQuery UI, into a CKEditor (jQuery version) window. The source in the editor was updated accordingly. Serendipity!

But it was like I had just seen a unicorn --  It only happened once, and I was not able to replicate the effect.

Has anyone else been able to get those two tools to work together? If so, what's the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you don't need to make an image "draggable" with jquery to drag it into CkEditor. It works out of the box with any image of the page.